# Television Radio Module or Circuit

Tags: rf, radio, frequency-modulation, tv, software-defined-radio

I want to listen TV channels without display (terrestrial) just like FM Radio 
channels. There are lots of FM receiver circuits on the web but I couldn't find for TV channels. Is such a thing possbile for beginners or it is just an advanved topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be possible, since the audio for the old-style analog TV was just an FM subcarrier. You could relatively easily modify the frequency coverage of an ordinary broadcast FM receiver to cover the VHF TV band.

However, since all terrestrial broadcasting has now shifted to digital, you need an actual digital TV receiver chip, or the functional equivalent, in order have any chance of getting an audio stream out of it.

You might be able to do (and learn) something useful with one of the many Software-Defined Radio kits that are now on the market. Or just get a digital TV card for your computer and only listen to the audio.